# Passing different types of data to void pointer function to add to a network packet (I think?)

Tags: c++, networking, void-pointers

**EDIT TO CODE** I derped up really bad with the code below when I originally posted.  The problem I had in the end was that I was getting the "sizeof" of the size value which I had already passed to the function. Thus I was always writing 4bytes instead the actual size. Basically I did something like this:

```
size = sizeof(valueIWantToSend);
finalSizeToWrite = sizeof(size); //derpderpderp
```

I have fixed the example code below.

---

Tried to do something a little bit more complex to try and clean up my code when creating a packet of network data to be sent.

The idea is to have a function like:

**AppendPacket(dataToBeSent, sizeOfData)**

The part I'm stuck on is getting the dataToBeSent to copy across correctly via this function.

Previously I would have a few messy lines of "memcopy" which would stuff the data into the buffer in a specified position. This way works, tried and tested. Despite the example below, its messy and a paint to maintain.

```
memcpy((char*)GetBufferPositionIndex(), (char*)&dataToBeSent, sizeof(sizeof(dataToBeSent)));
StepBufferPositionForward(sizeof(dataToBeSent));
```

So yeah, thats a more understandable version of what I currently use in various places throughout my game code to package data I need to send to multiplayer clients.

Instead of copying those lines all over the place I want to use my AppendPacket() function. Initially it looks something similar to this:

```
//How I tend to use the function in my code
double playerVelocity = 22.34;
AppendPacket( &playerVelocity, sizeof(playerVelocity) );


//Definition
AppendPacket( void* dataToBeSent, size_t sizeOfData )
{
     memcpy( (char*)GetBufferPositionIndex(), dataToBeSent, sizeof(sizeOfData) );
     StepBufferPositionForward( sizeof(sizeOfData) );
}
```

From what I can tell by debugging, is that I'm actually sending the address of the data  and not the actual data it self.

I've tried various combinations of the the pointer symbol and address symbol through the function and "dataToBeSent" part, but I'm not having any luck :(

The above needs to work with all sorts of data formats such as structs, arrays of characters, single bytes, doubles, ints, floats, etc.

Any ideas as to how I'm suppose to be doing it?  Been racking my brain all night and morning :(

---

For the curious:
The **GetBufferPositionIndex()** essentially returns the position of where to begin writing next in the buffer.

```
unsigned char packetToBeSentBuffer[PACKET_SIZE];
unsigned char* bufferIndexCurrent;
unsigned char* bufferIndexStartPosition;

unsigned char* GetBufferPositionIndex();
void StepBufferPositionForward(int sizeOfVar);

unsigned char* GetBufferPositionIndex()
{
     return bufferIndexCurrent;
}

void PlayerObj::StepBufferPositionForward(int sizeOfVar)
{
     bufferIndexCurrent += sizeOfVar;
     if (messageToSendIndex > (( bufferIndexStartPosition + PACKET_SIZE) - 200))
     {
           cout << "WARNING: Packet for this tick has less than 200 bytes left until full\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide deteails about the `GetBufferPositionIndex()` function? Are those methods of a socket-like class?

Comment: Are all those members/methods part of the same class? or global? I would suggest making them part of the "client" or "server" - the ones who handle the packets. Having a fixed packet size is also very error prone- you could exceed it at any time.

Comment: Yeah theres a lot I could do to improve the creation of packets and error handling. Will get around to it at some point. The main problem I have at the moment is that copying of data.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure where the exact problem is right now without knowing how the code eventually gets to socket reads/writes, and how your buffer works, but here is a suggestion for now, to further simplify your code.

The code is still error prone as it is up to you to make sure the size of the data you're passing is correct. One wrong copy paste of your new function with the wrong size, and you have bugs again. For these cases I always suggest a simple template:

```
template <typename T>
AppendPacket( T& data )
{
    std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
    memcpy( some_destination, &data, size );
    StepBufferPositionForward( size );
}

struct whatever a;
AppendPacket(a);

double b;
AppendPacket(b);

int c[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
AppendPacket(c);
```

This way, the compiler figures out the size of the data for you each time.

About the buffer, having a fixed size will be problematic, because currently AppendPacket does not handle the case when the packet size is exceeded. There are two solutions:

- Throw an exception when getting the position to write within the buffer
- Have a dynamically resizeable buffer

I'll give an example of how to handle the second case:

```
class Client
{
    std::vector<char> nextPacket;

public:

    template <typename T>
    AppendToPacket( T& data )
    {
        // figure out the size
        std::size_t size = sizeof(T);

        // expand vector to accomodate more space
        nextPacket.reserve(size);

        // append the data to the vector
        std::copy_n( static_cast<char const*>(&data),
                     size,
                     std::back_inserter(nextPacket) );
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this answer, it doesn't address my original issue from what I can tell, without a load of refactoring, which I'm not going to do yet.  Plus I need to learn a bit more about Templates as I don't use them currently. Need to find out why I was getting the address of my datablob instead of the actual datablob written to my buffer.

Comment: I derped, When you originally looked at my code above I forgot to add a very important part. I have now updated the examples.  Hopefully someone will find use of what you've done :)

Comment: Hey! So doesn't your explanation solve your problem? You were passing the wrong size, giving rise to your problem. The fact that you manually pass the size each time is why that error happened. My first answer should resolve the problem- templates don't have to get complicated if you stay simple. Think of it as just another parameter `T` to your function (`template <typename T>`), but it's a _type_, and the compiler figures it out for you at compile time (no runtime cost). It's a win-win.

Comment: Yeah, since updating the way I pass the size through the functions, its working as expected. I have not implemented your template suggestion as its too much to get my head around at the moment. Will look at it again when I do another pass of cleaning up my code in the future :)